# Using subclass objects in superclass object

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm kinda new to `Java`, so I have a, rather dumb, question: Is it possible to have and use subclass'es objects in superclass which too have a constructor?

Here's an example what I want to do: I have Superclass `Team` and subclass `Player`. I want to create `Player` object, which contains variables like `name`, `surname`, `height`, etc. . And I want to access this `Player` object in `Team` class, which have it's name, positions and other variables, to assign the `Player` object to his position in the `Team`. Lets say, `Player: John Doe` is in `Team` named `Red` and he is a `Goalkeeper`.

And all together, is it possible to access all of this in `main` function? For example I want to print out all Team Red's players names.

Sorry, it's kinda complicated to explain what I want to do, but isn't this have to do something with `extends`?

Comment: Sure it is possible, but why would a `Player` be a subclass of `Team`? Semantically this would mean "each Player is a Team", which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: @Turing85 is right. It would make sens to have a private List<Player> players in the Team class instead of having Player subclass the Team class

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I messed up everything. `Player` should be superclass for `Team`. Nevertheless is it possible to have one class for `Team` and one for `Player` insted of one with team and player and use it together?

Comment: @RimantasRadžiūnas that still does not make sense, since this implys that "each Team is a Player". Look at Kevin Workman's answer for an in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that yes, this is possible.

The longer answer is that you're misusing the terms **superclass** and **subclass**. The relationship you describe is not an **is-a** relationship of inheritance, but a **has-a** relationship of composition.

In other words, your Player class does not extend your Team class. Your Team class would contain instances of Player. And yes, in that case your Team class could access the methods and variables of those instances, just like you can any other Java class. It might look something like this:

```
class Team{
   List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

   public void addPlayer(Player p, String position){
      p.position = position;
      players.add(p);
   }
}
```

And then from a main() method, you might do something like this:

```
public class Main{
   public static void main(String... args){
      Team team = new Team("Fighting Cats");
      Player p = new Player("Johnny Appleseed");
      team.addPlayer(p, "Apple Picker");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, Kevin. Really informative and now I've got the idea what I was asking. But one problem occurs, does variable `position` have to be `public` so class `Team` can access it? Because now I am using `private String position;` in `Player` class. And compiler gives me an error that there is no `position` in `Team` class.

Comment: @RimantasRadžiūnas My code is just an example. In your case, right, you would not be able to access the position variable directly. You might add a public setPosition() function to your Player class and access it that way instead.

Comment: And other question: If I store more than one variable in Player object, `addPlayer` function will add object with all the variables? Or it can be only one variable?

Comment: @RimantasRadžiūnas Like I said, my code is just an example. You can use whatever variables you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see the below code.

```
public class Team{
  public Player player;
}

class Player extends Team{
  public Team team;
}
```

Although, I doubt your logic and design when you say that `Player` extends `Team`, which essentially says that a `Player` is a `Team`. This would mean that each `Player` object would have a list of players and positions (as subtypes inherit non-private states and behaviours from supertypes), which doesn't make much sense semantically.

I suggest that you instead approach it like the following.

```
public class Team{
    public LinkedList<Player> players;
}

class Player{
    public Position position; // Use some way of defining the player's position.
}
```

This means that `Team` would have a `Player`, rather `Player` being a `Team`

Answer (score 1):

You have to create 3 classes Team, Player & a Client class to input the data.
I am writing the skeleton code for you. It will give you an idea as to how to write your code

```
public class Team {

    ArrayList<Player> player;

    public ArrayList<Player> getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void setPlayer(ArrayList<Player> player) {
        this.player = player;
    }
}
```

Player

```
class Player{

    String name;
    Integer score;
    Integer Rank;

 //getter setters 
}
```

Client class

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Player pOne = new Player();
        pOne.setRank(2);
        pOne.setName("ABD");

        Player pTwo=new Player();
        pTwo.setRank(2);
        pTwo.setName("SPC");
        pTwo.setTotal(60);

        ArrayList<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
        playerList.add(pOne);
        playerList.add(pTwo);

        Team team=new Team();
        one.setPlayer(playerListOne);

//get the player using Team class's getPlayer method & print
}
```

You need not use `extends` but rather focus on the OO design.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a composition and not inheritance (i.e. A `Team` "has a" `Player`. "A  `Player` is a `Team`" does not make much sense)

```
class Player {
    String name;
    String surname;
    String height;
}

class Team {
    String name;
    List<Player> players;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When we think about team and player, its relation is **team has a player**.
Use the same relation when you design the classes. 
Position is a property which is relevant in the scope of a Player. So introduce that property in correct level. Better to keep Team class with its own properties.